# How do you prove that a function is independent of a variable in an interval?

Tags: solution-verification

I was doing basic excercises about proofs but I am lost with this one.

"Prove taht if a is a fixed value in the interval {$0<a<\pi$}, then for every number t in the interval {$ 0 \le t \le \pi$ -a}, then:

$$ F(x) = \frac{sin(t) + sin(t+a)}{cos(t) + cos(t+a)} $$ is an independent from t.

I will also leave the original text in spanish just in case I misstranslated something
mostrar "marcha atrás" que si a es un número fijo que verifica {$0<a<\pi$},
entonces para cualquier número t que verifica {$ 0 \le t \le \pi$ -a}, resulta que
$$ F(x) = \frac{sin(t) + sin(t+a)}{cos(t) + cos(t+a)} $$
es un valor independiente de t.

Comment: Do you mean $F(t)$?  The right hand is not a function of $x$.  And it is not a constant function of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the formula of the sum of the sinus and cosinus:

$$
\sin(a) + \sin(b) = 2\sin(\frac{a+b}{2})\cos(\frac{a-b}{2})
$$
$$
\cos(a) + \cos(b) = 2\cos(\frac{a+b}{2})\cos(\frac{a-b}{2})
$$

With this in mind, we can simplify $F(t)$:
$$
F(t) = \frac{2\sin(\frac{t+t+a}{2})\cos(\frac{t-t-a}{2})}{2\cos(\frac{t+t+a}{2})\cos(\frac{t-t-a}{2})} = \frac{\sin(t+\frac{a}{2})}{\cos(t+\frac{a}{2})} = \tan(t+\frac{a}{2})
$$

Which is not a constant value. Maybe you made some error while writing the problem?

Comment: Thank you very much,.

Comment: This proves that not only is $F(t)$ not independent of $t$, it is not even defined for every $t$ in the interval $[0,\pi-a]$. Specifically, for $t=\frac12(\pi-a)$, we have $\cos(t+a/2) = 0$.